# Possible memory leak caused by ubuntu bluetooth stack while scanning for devices?

Tags: bluetooth, dbus

I have a Nvidia Jetson TX2 running `Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.9.140+ aarch64)` and using bluetooth to identify specific devices based on their device name and advertisment data. It seems that the system I'm using has a `Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275` card (at least according to `lshw`, whole system I'm using is a bit of a black box)

Now I have the problem, that while scanning for BLE devices, my memory fills up till it's completely full. This happens when using [Bleak](https://bleak.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) from a custom python script, as well when using `bluetoothctl` for scanning. The only method to free the memory is by stopping the bluetooth scan and wait a few hours. A reboot also seems to help in some cases.

In detail, the filesystem looks like the following, where the available space on `/dev/mmcblk0p1` gets less over time when having the bluetooth scan turned on:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk0p1   14G   13G  514M  97% /
none            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G   13M  1.9G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  204M  1.7G  11% /run
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           384M     0  384M   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs           384M     0  384M   0% /run/user/1000
```

What I noticed was, that when I use `bluetoothctl`, everytime a device is discovered or the parameters of a device changes, the used memory increases. I have not yet noticed any process increasing it's memory usage, so it is really hard to pin-point the exact cause. But it certainly has to do with the bluetooth scan results that may get logged/cached somewhere? I have not yet found any specific file or folder that increases in size...

At this point I don't know where/how to look further into the issue, so I hoped that maybe here anybody had a similar issue or ideas how to further debug this?

Don't know if the description is enough information to make sense, if not, I'm sorry, debugging this meltes my brain day by day a bit more....

Comment: The devices that BlueZ finds are cached in /var/lib/bluetooth but you should never need to look in there. The BlueZ API allows for devices to be deleted from the cache. There is an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65937350/7721752) that scans for devices and then deletes/removes them after processing the information.

Comment: Another question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/66465459/7721752) about a possible memory leak on BlueZ active scanning that might be of interest to you....

Comment: Others have indeed observed similar issues. I suggest you log an issue here: https://github.com/bluez. Let's see what they say...

Comment: thanks for the replies, will take a look/try out the suggestion and update this post when I find out more