# Capture bluetooth beacons from a specific device

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I need to capture [BLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_Low_Energy) beacons and inspect their content. Having failed to convince `wireshark` to do that, I discovered the plain `bluetoothctl` from package `bluez` does it:

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
Discovery started
[CHG] Controller CC:15:31:5F:73:4A Discovering: yes
[NEW] Device 49:DA:89:B3:9B:19 49-DA-89-B3-9B-19
[NEW] Device 20:C9:D0:47:DB:AA 20-C9-D0-47-DB-AA
[NEW] Device 60:72:21:DF:F9:A4 60-72-21-DF-F9-A4
[NEW] Device 52:CF:9F:A6:85:C9 52-CF-9F-A6-85-C9
[NEW] Device 66:A6:75:A7:2E:69 66-A6-75-A7-2E-69
[NEW] Device 6C:D9:CF:B3:9F:34 6C-D9-CF-B3-9F-34
[NEW] Device 68:B3:E4:9B:27:36 68-B3-E4-9B-27-36
[NEW] Device 7E:F6:07:0E:CC:9F 7E-F6-07-0E-CC-9F
[NEW] Device 56:AA:85:3D:4B:EB 56-AA-85-3D-4B-EB
[NEW] Device 4C:C9:5E:33:42:09 4C-C9-5E-33-42-09
[NEW] Device 7A:FC:C2:18:ED:9C 7A-FC-C2-18-ED-9C
[CHG] Device 4C:C9:5E:33:42:09 Class: 0x000c043c
[CHG] Device 4C:C9:5E:33:42:09 Icon: audio-card
```

My problem is that my environment is rather noisy thus following the beacons from a single device is difficult(and I would like to monitor in real time). How to filter the output by a UUID as if `grep`ing?

Bonus question: what is `[CNG]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a new device is discovered BlueZ indicates this with `[NEW]`. When a [property](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/device-api.txt#n123) of an already discovered device CHanGes then it uses `[CHG]`.

BlueZ allows discovery report to be filtered with SetDiscoveryFilter. More information at: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc/adapter-api.txt

In `bluetoothctl` this is accessed from commands under `menu scan`.

If you want to do this with code I would generally recommend using the API's provided by BlueZ and documented at:
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/doc

I have posted a Python example before at:
[bluetootctl scan on parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936587/bluetootctl-scan-on-parsing/65937350#65937350)

The BlueZ D-Bus APIs can be accessed from any programming language that has D-Bus bindings.

Comment: Awesome answer with links and details! I'll wait a couple of days before accepting in case a bash one-liner with standard tools exists.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to discover my device. Perhaps because it's Bluetooth Low Energy, which is incompatible protocol with Bluetooth?

Comment: It should find both BLE and Classic devices. It will only find `[NEW]` and not `[CHG]` so if you device is in returned by `bluetoothctl devices` then the script will not find it. Delete it before starting the script. To get more debug information have `bluetoothctl` window open. Also open a terminal with `sudo btmon` for low-level informaiton (Also, the output of `btmon` can be taken into `wireshark` if you are familiar with that.