# How can I read, with python and Raspberry, the Service Data sent in the advertising pack of a beacon?

Tags: python, sensors, ibeacon

I am using a beacon that advertise each 100ms a data packet, that contains sensor datas in the "Service Data" segment of the ADV package.
I want to read these dataswith a python program, onboarded on a Raspberry PI3B+.
I have imported the Bleak Library, but I do not know how to use it.
I think my problem is simple to resolve, but I am a rookie....

Thanks to everyone can help me.

Regards

Service data are correctly received by the classic phones apps (nrf connect for example) whithout a connection to the beacon (juste by readig the ADV information).
I have found code example to scan beacon, but no example treats the "servicedata" content, just UUID, Major/Minor, ...etc.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are having a problem with?  There is a Bleak example that returns advertising data https://github.com/hbldh/bleak/blob/develop/examples/discover.py. What does this not do for you? Is your issue decoding the byte content of the advertisement? Are you using a custom format for the beacon?  Or is it one of the "standard" formats? https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/beacon-advertising-cheat-sheet/

Comment: Hi. I can return advertising datas with your bleak example. But my beacon sends advertising evry 100ms and the python script is very slow. If I reduce the "sleep" parameter, it do not detect antyhting. Do you know how to select a specific device, and target detection to increase the acquisition frequency ?

Comment: More over, th service data packet looks like "AdvertisementData(local_name='Holy', manufacturer_data={76: b"\x02\x15\xfd\xa5\x06\x93\xa4\xe2O\xb1\xaf\xcf\xc6\xeb\x07dx%'\x1b'\x1b\xc9"}, service_data={'00005242-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb': b'AT\x0f\xff?\x00\x00\x00\x01@'}, rssi=-73)". Only the part after "b'AT\" interests me because this part contains sensor measuremnts (X,Y,Z accelerometer in my case). How do you transform it into integer values ? Thanks a lot

Comment: To convert the bytes to integers you would normally use `int.from_bytes` or `struct.unpack` but how the bytes are packed I couldn't guess from the information you've shared.

Comment: There is an alternative implementation of scanning for beacons at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936587/bluetootctl-scan-on-parsing/65937350#65937350. For your needs you would need to change `ManufacturerData` for `ServiceData` in the example

Comment: I thank you for your answer. The alternative implementation is ok, but I have still the same problem. My beacon is set to advertise every 100ms, and I do not know how to filter the scan only on this beacon, and how to collect all the advetisements (one per 100ms).

Comment: In the exemple, I add a filter on "name", but service data appears randomly, every 1 or 2 or more seconds. Some times, I collect nothing for 10 or 20 seconds, and suddenly, a service data package is red. When I try to read servicedata with a phone application, such as LightBlue, or nrfConnect, I can see the service data been updated each 100ms. So, I'm sure it is possible to get the highest collect frequency. I simply do not know how to do that in python (and i am a novice in programming, the constructor told me the android API, but it is too difficult for me, so what I use python).