# Data logging data from BLE beacons

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, embedded-linux

I'm currently building some Bluetooth LE beacons that sense some parameters and send the data every 20s.

I'm trying to gather all the data to process it on a laptop / raspberry pi.

I essentially need to specifically target the beacons (I have LOTS of BLE devices around).

They will all have the same naming convention : 06:05:04:03:xx:xx (where xx is the device number).

How do I write some code that would be able to gather the data and log it in a .csv ?

I was able to "see" them with the following lines :

```
$bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# menu scan
[bluetooth]# clear
[bluetooth]# transport le
[bluetooth]# duplicated-data on
[bluetooth]# back
[bluetooth]# scan on
```

I don't really know how to proceed as I'm new to this kind of technology.

Edit : In the end, I went the nRF52840 + Wireshark route for simplicity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bluetootctl scan on parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65936587/bluetootctl-scan-on-parsing)

Comment: @ukBaz, kind of, I just ran the script, I couldn't detect the beacon… Even after increasing the TX from every 20s to every 1s.

Comment: If you do `bluetoothctl devices` are your devices in the list? If they are then script will not report them. You will need to remove the devices first or update the script to report "PropertiesChanged". I would also suggest you have other terminals open to see what `sudo btmon` and `bluetoothctl` are reporting when you run the script.